# Writing data on to CSV file is changing the characters

Tags: python, csv, praw

Im using praw to extract data from reddit however when i save it to a csv file its changing some of the characters for example "That’s actually really good" is changed to "Thatâ€™s actually really good".

Here is the code I'm using

```
import praw
import csv
import itertools
from praw.models import MoreComments



    with open ('WriteRow.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding="utf-8") as f:
       fieldnames = ['Submission_ID','Submission_Title','Submission_Comments']
       writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
       writer.writeheader()

       subred = reddit.subreddit("FortNiteBR")
    

       hot_apex = subred.top(limit=20)

       hot_apex = list(hot_apex)

       for submission in hot_apex:
            if submission.link_flair_text == 'SUGGESTION':
                i = str(submission) # makes i the string version of sub id 
                writer.writerow({'Submission_ID' : submission.id,'Submission_Title' : submission.title})
                count = 0
                for comment in sub_id.comments:
                    if hasattr(comment, 'body'):
                       count = count + 1
                       if count < 10:
                          writer.writerow({'Submission_Comments' : comment.body})
                          print ({'Submission_Comments' : comment.body})`
```

Comment: Where do you see these altered characters?  If it's in an application like Excel, are you specifying that the file is encoded as UTF-8 when opening it?

Comment: How do i specify the file is opened as UTF-8?

Comment: I believe there's an option to select the encoding in Excel's open dialog.   You could also try writing the csv with the utf-8-sig encoding (`open ('WriteRow.csv', 'w', newline='',encoding="utf-8-sig")`) which Excel may detect automatically.  However note that applications on non-Windows machines may not recognise this encoding.